# Cant create a second layout xml file in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml

Im using Mac, and want to create layout xml file in **'res/layout'**. I right-click on the layout folder, select an '**Android XML file'**, put File Name, Resource Type and the name of the project in the new window. But as i click finish it wont work. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the Android SDK for Eclipse or something else?

Comment: Android SDK for Eclipse, sorry for not mentioning. peace

Comment: Hi @IronBlossom, did you ever find a fix for your problem?

Comment: @IntrepidBrit right click on a existing layout xml then Open with>>Android Common XML editor fixed it. It doesn't bug me anymore since i updated my ADT.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Mac, you should **ctrl-click** the layout file, then select "Open With..." and "Android Layout Editor"

Comment: i cant add another xml file in layout folder... i guess now im clear

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce this on my MacOSX 10.7.2 + Eclipse 3.7 + ADT r14.

Try press F5 or fn+F5 to refresh Eclipse workspace.

If still not seeing it, try this. Drop the exited one (`main.xml`) to same folder to copy a new xml file.